Incorrect OR evaluation of cell range
Edited
I have a custom formula in conditional fange that fails to do the expected.
The condition depends on 3 factors with AND and OR spanning on a range from line 2 to 726.
=and(X2>1000,OR(AC2="–",AC2+90<today())).
The OR par evaluate the Less than today() but does not evaluate cells content of hyphen.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Eventually I had to replace the OD with IF:
=and(X2>1000, if(AC2="–",true,AC2+90<today()))
Thanks @Harun24hr for teaching that it's enough to specify the condition on a single cell. And to @rockinfreakshow that points to the error in arithmetic operations on the hyphen. I was under the wrong assumption that OR part are evaluated left to right... That explains why the IF solves the issue.

Conditional formatting automatically check each cell based on apply range. You may try =AND($X2>1000,OR($AC2="-",$AC2+90<today())).

You must check cell value is hyphen - or due to cell formatting it is showing -.

When its a hyphen –, the condition AC2:AC726+90<today() evaluates to an error & not to TRUE/FALSE since the condition is tryin' to add number to a text
